# ReactJS rendering doesn't work with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I started to learn ReactJS and I have a task to build a simple user managing app with Rails back-end and ReactJS front-end. The back-end tasks are completed (to create, update, show and delete user's data), but I'm a little stuck with front-end. I started from the most simple: added gem `react-rails`, ran `bundle install` & `rails g react:install`, all the necessary files were generated. So, in my code I have:

**welcome_controller.rb**

```
def index
    @users = User.all
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= react_components 'Users', { data: @users } %>
```

**application.js**

```
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
```

**assets/javascripts/components/users.js.coffee**

```
@users = React.createClass
render: ->
    React.DOM.div
        className: 'users'
        React.DOM.h2
            className: 'title'
            'Users'
```

But in the **index.html.erb** nothing is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I've got my error - while I have 'Users' component to render in my view (capitalized), in my react file i have `@users`. So, there's just lack of attention :(